# A question about a structure theorem of $R$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am reading "An Introduction to Algebraic Systems" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

> Theorem 10:
> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain.
> Let $L$ be a free $R$-module.
> Let $N$ be a submodule of $L$.
> Then, $N$ is also a free module and $\operatorname{rank}N\leq\operatorname{rank}L$.

> Theorem 11:
> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain.
> Let $L$ be a free $R$-module.
> Let $N$ be a submodule of $L$.
> Let $n:=\operatorname{rank}L, r:=\operatorname{rank}N (r\leq n)$.
> Then, there are a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $L$ and non-zero elements $a_1,\dots,a_r$ of $R$ such that $\{a_1e_1,\dots,a_re_r\}$ is a basis of $N$ and $a_1\mid a_2,\,\, a_2\mid a_3,\,\, \dots,\,\,a_{r-1}\mid a_r$.

The author wrote as follows:

> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain.
> Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module.
> Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a generator of $M$.
> Let $L$ be a free $R$-module such that $\operatorname{rank}L=n$ and its basis is $\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$.
> Let $f:L\to M$ be a mapping such that $f(\sum_{i=1}^n c_iu_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv_i (c_i\in R)$.
> Then, $f$ is a surjective $R$-homomorphism.
> Let $N:=\operatorname{Ker}f$.
> Then, $L/N\cong M$.
> By Theorem 11, there are a new basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $L$ and non-zero elements $a_1,\dots,a_r$ of $R$ such that $\{a_1e_1,\dots,a_re_r\}$ is a basis of $N$ and $a_1\mid a_2,\,\, a_2\mid a_3,\,\, \dots,\,\,a_{r-1}\mid a_r$.
> Then, $$L=\langle e_1\rangle_R\oplus\dots\oplus\langle e_r\rangle_R\oplus\dots\oplus\langle e_n\rangle_R,$$$$N=\langle a_1e_1\rangle_R\oplus\dots\oplus\langle a_re_r\rangle_R.$$
> $$L/N\cong(\bigoplus_{i=1}^r \langle e_i\rangle_R/\langle a_ie_i\rangle_R)\oplus\langle e_{r+1}\rangle_R\oplus\dots\oplus\langle e_n\rangle_R.$$
> Since $\langle e_i\rangle_R/\langle a_ie_i\rangle_R\cong R/(a_i)$ and $\langle e_j\rangle_R\cong R$, $$M\cong(\bigoplus_{i=1}^r R/(a_i))\oplus \overbrace{R\oplus\dots\oplus R}^{\text{s}}\,\,(r+s=n).$$
> The ideals $(a_i)$ satisfy $$(a_1)\supset(a_2)\supset\dots\supset (a_r).$$
> There is a possibility that $(a_1)=(a_2)=\dots=(a_k)=R$.
> If $(a_1)=(a_2)=\dots=(a_k)=R$, then $R/(a_1)=R/(a_2)=\dots=R/(a_k)=\{0\}$.
> We can omit $R/(a_1)=R/(a_2)=\dots=R/(a_k)=\{0\}$ from $$M\cong(\bigoplus_{i=1}^r R/(a_i))\oplus \overbrace{R\oplus\dots\oplus R}^{\text{s}}\,\,(r+s=n).$$

Then the author wrote:

> If we take a system of generators $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of $M$ such that $\#\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is smallest, then any $(a_i)$ such that $(a_i)=R$ doesn't appear in $$M\cong(\bigoplus_{i=1}^r R/(a_i))\oplus \overbrace{R\oplus\dots\oplus R}^{\text{s}}\,\,(r+s=n).$$

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r+s<n$, then $M$ is isomorphic to a module which has less than $n$ generators, a contradiction.

Comment: user26857, Thank you very much for your answer and edit.